# Not All Threads are used to invoke methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using the Thread constructor to create threads. I was expecting the below code to be executed by 3 separate threads and different outputs.
Can anyone please explain why is the output different from my understanding(why is thread 2 is used to invoke m1 twice and not t3)?

**Code:-**

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new SynchronizedExample().execute();
}

void execute() {
    SynchronizedExample s1 = new SynchronizedExample();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(s1::m1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(s1::m1);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(s1::m2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}

public synchronized void m1(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Current Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("M1");
}

public void m2() {
    System.out.println("M2");
}
}
```

**Output:-**

```
Current Thread - Thread-0
M2
M1
Current Thread - Thread-1
M1
```

**Expected Output:-**

```
Current Thread - Thread-0
M2
Current Thread - Thread-1
M1
Current Thread - Thread-2
M1
```

Comment: `m2` doesn't print out the current thread name.  So the output is exactly what you'd expect.  Thread 0 has picked up `m1`, and prints `Current Thread - Thread-0` then `M1`.  While that's happening, thread 2 has picked up `m2` and just prints `m2`.  Thread 1 has picked up the _other_ `m1` (at some point, can't tell) but can't start because the method's `synchronized`, so prints `Current Thread - Thread-1` and then `M1` as soon as Thread 0 has dropped the monitor.

Comment: You don't have a `System.out.println("Current Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());` in m2 and m2 is not synchronized.

Comment: By the way, output from threaded calls to `System.out.println` do not always appear on the console in chronological order. Always include a timestamp such as `Instant.now()` to study if you want to see true sequence. Or use a thread-safe collection for output strings rather than `System.out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made it confusing.

I'll annotate your output:

> ```
> Current Thread - Thread-0 [t1 - m1]
> M2 [t3 - m2]
> M1 [t1 - m1]
> Current Thread - Thread-1 [t2 - m1]
> M1 [t2 - m1]
> ```

Your code prints something, then waits, then prints more. Thus, a single method gets its System.out lines smeared across the first and third line. Your m2 method **does not print** `Current Thread - ...` at all, so what you expect obviously couldn't possibly happen. Add a print.

Comment: Thanks! it was an overlook from my side.